# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and angle between vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, angle, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $\langle x,y\rangle=x\cdot y$ be the standard dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, for $x,y$ non-zero, we have 
$$-1 \leq \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}\leq 1.$$

Thus there exists unique $\theta$ such that $\cos\theta$ is equal to the middle quantity in the above inequality. This $\theta$ is called as angle between $x$ and $y$.

However, while looking at proofs of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I came across one proof where it proceeds as follows:

> *since $\cos\theta=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}$, taking modulus, we obtain $\left|\langle x,y\rangle\right|\leq \|x\|\|y\|$, which proves Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.*

**Question:** Which of the two approaches is correct?

(1) Prove Cauchy-Schwarz inequality first and using it define angle between two vectors?

(2) Define angle between two (non-zero) vectors by $\cos\theta=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}$ and use it to prove Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: It depends on what *basic* definitions your start with. For example, high schools here usually **define** the standard dot product precisely as $$x\cdot y=||x||\,||y||\cos\theta$$ with $\;\theta=$ the angle between both vectors. This definition is rather poor for universities, say...but it is a starting point to work.

Comment: You second approach does not work because you should first show that the right hand side is $\le 1$ so it can be the cosine of something (which is what you do in the first approach)
Instead, as @Timbuc say you could define the scalar product in that way, but it is not optimal for a lots of reasons (What the heck is an angle in a $17$-dimensional space? What is the angle between two functions in the hilbert space $L^2$? )These example show that the first approach is easy to generalize if one wants, the other not so much and it does not make much sense as long as you leave $\Bbb R^3$

Answer (score 5):

Take a parameter $\;a\in\Bbb R\;$, and since we're in a real linear space we have for any two vectors $\;x,y\;$ :

$$0\stackrel{\text{axiom!}}\le\langle ax+y\,,\,ax+y\rangle=||x||^2a^2+2\langle x,y\rangle a+||y||^2$$

Thus, the above is a non-negative quadratic *in* $\;a\;$ and thus its discrimimnant is non-positive (i.e. the corresponding parabola meets the $\;x$ - axis at most in one point):

$$\Delta=(2\langle x,y\rangle)^2-4||x||^2||y||^2\le0\implies|\langle x,y\rangle|\le||x||\,||y||$$

which is the Cauchy-Schwarz-Buniakovski inequality, without trigonometry and stuff, only very basic algebra.

Even now in graduate school, I find the above the easiest, most elegant *and basic* proof of this inequality in the real case.

Comment: How does this answer address the questions raised in the first post?

Comment: I think it does answer what it must answer: first, it gives a proof of CSB inequality without any need of angles, cosines and stuff, from which **then** we can *define* cosine of angle between vectors and stuff. This clears both (1)-(2), and the other question "which approach is right", besides being addressed already in other comments/answers, depends heavily on the first, basic definitions given, and I address this with an example in my comment below the question.

Comment: Of course, another option is to downvote what you don't understand, @daw...:) Oh, well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof that
$$\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|} \in [-1,1]$$
which is **not** using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Basically, the idea is to see this as the variational characterization of the singular values of the identity matrix, i.e. its Rayleigh quotient. Let $$f(x,y)=\frac{\langle x,y \rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}.$$ Then, for every $x,y\neq 0$, we have $f(x,y)=f\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|},\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right)$. Since $f$ is smooth on $S=\{(x,y)\mid \|x\|=\|y\|=1\}$ it reaches its maximum and minimum values on $S$. All critical points of $f$ in $S$ must satisfy 
$$\nabla f(x,y)=0 \iff \left\{\begin{array}{l l} x=\langle x,y\rangle y \\ y=\langle x,y\rangle x\end{array}\right. \iff \left\{\begin{array}{l l} x=(\langle x,y\rangle)^2 x \\ y=(\langle x,y\rangle)^2 y\end{array}\right. \iff \langle x,y\rangle\in \{-1,1\}$$
and the associated critical value is $\langle x,y\rangle$. 
And thus the minimum of $f$ is $-1$ and its maximum is $1$.

Comment: This was unfortunately too long to be a comment.

Comment: Can you prove all the necessary prerequisites without Cauchy-Schwarz? After all, you use a *lot* of advanced techniques: compactness, multi-variate calculus, critical points.

Comment: @daw If you assume that $\|x\|= \langle x,x\rangle$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm, YES! However, the margin is too small to include the proof. The analysis lecture I had in first year shows all the required material to understand this proof without using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality (under the assumptions cited above).

Comment: I assume you mean $\Vert x \Vert = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$. I for my part though do not know of a proof that this $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ satisfies the triangle inequality, i.e. does define a norm, which does not use Cauchy-Schwarz to begin with. So I consider this proof circular, but I would be happy to see this objection refuted.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Well, in principle, you don't need the triangle inequality to make the derivations in my answer. Homogeneity (to use the compactness argument) and positivity (to ensure that $f$ and $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$ are well defined) are enough.

Comment: If we don't know that $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ satisfies the triangle inequailty, then we don't know that $d(x,y):= \Vert x- y \Vert$ is a metric. Without metric, $S$ has no chance to be compact. (And by the way, this compactness part only goes through for finite-dimensional spaces even if we can somehow fix this; I admit that is part of the question, just pointing out that this shows this proof fails for more general Hilbert spaces regardless.)

Comment: Hey again, I probably sound like an ass, but although I really like the spirit behind this answer, and think it gives useful context and methods applicable elsewhere, for now I have to conclude that it fails in its main goal, hence downvote. I don't see what metric we are using to conclude $S$ is compact unless we already invoke CS. Further, even if we knew that $\Vert x \Vert$ defines a norm and $\Vert x-y \Vert$ a metric, to rigorously show $S$ is compact is not trivial, we would need something close to equivalence of norms *and* Heine-Borel, i.e. something tailor-made for $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

(2) is not correct. The definition of the angle between two vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ is **based on** the Cauchy-Schwarz.　you just cannot use it to prove what it's based on.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by: "The definition of the angle between two vectors in ℝn is based on the Cauchy-Schwarz."?

Comment: @Surb **because of** Cauchy-Schwarz, the value $a=\frac{\vec{u}\centerdot\vec{v}}{|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|}$ is always within $[-1,1]$, which makes it possible to **define** $a$ **as** the $\cos\theta$.

Comment: No... You can prove that $a\in [-1,1]$ without using Cauchy-Schwartz...

Comment: @Surb I'd like to learn how :P

Comment: See my answer in this question. Since you were the only one claiming that, I wrote it for this purpose.

Comment: @Surb Thanks a lot! But as it is rather complicated I think it'll take me some time to understand..

Comment: Sure. If you have any questions, just ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20843/discussion-between-vim-and-surb).

Answer (score 0):

I think at least in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you can take $\langle x,y\rangle = \lVert a\rVert \lVert b\rVert\cos \theta$ as the definition, then 
$$-1 \le \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\lVert a\rVert \lVert b\rVert}\le 1$$
all right.

But then you need to show that it's linear (which is difficult). So that you have the analytic form of the product which appears in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.